# String contains quotes in Visual Studio debugger but string.contains returns false

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

I have really weird behavior I have a string like in the picture:
[image: string contains quotes]

You can see the string `s` have quotes in the beginning and in the end but the function `s.Contains("\"")`
returns `false`. Someone help please what am I missing?

Comment: those begin/end quotes aren't really in the string.  Just the visualizer showing you it's a string

Comment: The string doesn't actually have any quotes. Those are added by Visual Studio when showing the string in the debugger.

Comment: [x] question answered in comments.

Comment: Try not to downvote - I am sure this has caught many a new Visual studio user out.

Comment: sorry I see people get angry my fault stupit question I will delete it!

Comment: @ilayzeidman, nah leave it - I am sure it will be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: It's how Visual Studio tells you the value is a String. If it didn't put the quotes in you wouldn't see a difference between (int) 1 and (String) 1.

Comment: I am 2 years experience in visual studio and this really make me trouble because I really thought there were quotes in the string... for now I am not deleting it if I see lot of downvotes I will delete it.

Comment: @ilayzeidman its a good question to leave up as other people may have similar questions. +1 for at least asking and providing details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As everyone has already stated in the comments, the Start and End quotes are added by Visual Studio when displaying a `string type`.

If you were to click the magnifer glass you will bring up the `Text Visualizer`. In the visualizer you will notice that the quotes are not visibile.

[image: Text Visualizer]

**Update: (per Alex suggestion)** Just to add here is the display of a string that contains quotes with the helper and the Text Visualizer.

[image: String with quote]

-Text Visualizer

[image: Visualizer with quotes]

- Immediate Window

[image: Immediate Window]

- Output window

[image: Output window]

Cheers.

Comment: +1. You may as well add answer to the second question of this type for `"foo\"bar"` output in debugger immediate window ( escaped quotes) to save future visitors time.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I'm ashamed to say that in years of using VS, that has caught me out once... :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov added some more examples from various VS Outputs.